# Google Cloud: Launch chrome in Windows VM

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want when starting a new VM (windows) in Google Compute Engine to launch google chrome.
I Tried s.th like this:

```
'key': 'windows-startup-script-cmd',
'value': '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"'
```

I noticed when I open Task manager I find chrome launched but not displayed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that by launching a program as part of the startup script, it is being launched in a desktop "session" that is not the same as the one you'd be connected to when you RDP in as a user. Just like if you had multiple RDP users connected to one server, they would not see the programs that each of them are running.